# PHP battle system integrity

Tags: php, mysql, system

I'm trying to write a php battle system for an online game I've been designing.

In short, it's going to be an MMORPG, and the players' stats will be saved across a couple of MySQL tables, as will the monster data.

In short, I'm worried about people doing something by either editing the monsters' hp on their end, so it says they killed the monster, keeping their HP max on their computer (because wouldn't it be unpractical to update a MySQL entry every turn?), or maybe something else.

I am still only intermediate on PHP, so not sure how I could have those values hidden from being changed by the user, yet not create a serious server congestion by updating the MySQL table every time there's an attack.

Could someone please tell me 1 or more of the following:

1. Is there a way in PHP alone to hide these active variables from being edited to allow cheating?
2. If not, or if it's not very server-friendly, is there a relatively simple applet in Java, or app for controlling host variables that could be programmed on a relatively simple manner?

Right now, monsters are only going to have regular attacks, and players will only have attacks, though I plan on expanding the players' skill attacks first.

Comment: You're getting downvoted because there is no real question here. You could have cut 3/4 of this question and still conveyed the message. I suggest you rethink what you're asking and try again.

Comment: First off, variables on the server side (PHP) can't be edited by users. Second off, in general, the way games generally work to prevent cheating is have a request to do something, and process the actual calculation server side. EX: Client requests to attack, server determines if they can, and how much damage it does and reports it back to the client, who already showed what they think it should look like, and should change if the server disagrees.

Comment: @Alex Lunix Thank you, I know the PHP itself can't be edited by users. 
My question is though, if you know anything about Cheat Engine, is that you can change what's in the browser's properties.

My fear is that users will use something of the sort to always make the BROWSER think they have max HP still, and RETURN that value to the server...

My question is how would I make it efficient to do what you said last? Using an MP example, wouldn't it eat bandwidth to constantly update the MP EVERY time you cast a spell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should never be trusting what the browser gives the to the server. The browser can make all the requests it wants (say, move 5000ft forward), but if the server looks at the request and says "Woah, you can't do that! The maximum speed is 2ft/second"! Then you just reject the "request to move", or you ignore it, your choice depending on implementation.

For example, the Client (be it a browser or an application on the desktop) can store all the data it wants.  It can store the HP and resources.  The server also has its own copy of these.  If someone were to use some memory altering tool (such as Cheat Engine), all they can do it modify the client's data (say, instead of 100 dollars to 1,000,000 dollars).  But this won't mean anything because if the client makes a request to purchase a 50,000 dollar item, the server will validate the request.  It looks at the money on the server, not the client, and notices that the user has insufficient funds.  Just tell the user "not enough money", and npo transaction is made.

If the client is going to try and mess with the client's internal memory, I would not worry about the client no longer functioning correctly.  Just make sure that the server approves all requests for game state modifications and everything will be fine.

If you want to avoid spamming the network and also keep movement of the user valid, the client can make the assumption that the server will approve the request.  So you can allow the user to move a certain distance and either send a single request after several seconds, or you can send several requests and show the character moving while you wait for the server to approve the requests.  This brings up a new issue of de-syncing with the server for the client if you make several requests and the server takes a while to respond.

In general, you will have to send a lot of requests, and you will have to send requests every time the user does something because you will want other users to see what you are doing, too.  There is no way to get around this, but you can use clever compression and delay tactics to allow the client to operate more smoothly.

If you want to avoid hitting your SQL servers all the time, you can use caching tools such as [Memcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php), which conveniently is very excellently supported by PHP.  Memcache can store whatever you need in memory for very fast data storage.  Of course, this has caveats as you will need to sync your cache with your database, and vice-versa.

Comment: Thank you, that's pretty much what Alex said, but I'm asking how can I do that without flooding the database query? In your example of moving, how could I set it to where the server knows I already move 6 feet, without updating it to move 2 feet once every second for 3 seconds? In my thoughts, wouldn't that put strain on the connection if several people are doing it? My server computer is powerful, but the bandwidth isn't too hot, and am trying to figure out the way lightest on bandwidth.

Comment: @Reidmere, the others above are right: SO is generally geared towards more specific questions.  I figured answering this question might help push you towards something more specific.

Comment: Thanks, I already voted you best answer for the time and detail you took... but I still am not straight on one answer. I like your idea for the movement thing, but I'm starting it initially as turnbased, as I stated. So on the idea of the MP example, how could I set it up in such a way the CURRENT MP keeps updating, without being a strain on the bandwidth to check the SQL *EACH TIME* if there's enough MP?
Or is that just a doomed fate I have, until I make an .exe carrier to run those real-time?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "until I made an .exe carrier".  PHP is interpreted and not compiled (although I suppose you could compile php code).

Comment: Also, I updated my answer about your SQL problem.

Comment: Somehow, certain browser games connect to a BASIC, C#, or C++ program that stores all static data (monster locations, current HPs, drops on floor, exc), then THAT send the PHP to the SQL. This is how many online games work, but I've not enough programming knowledge to do it yet... I was hoping SOMEBODY would, lol.

Comment: That is what Memcache is for.

Comment: Never heard of it honestly: Thanks, I'll look it up! :D
Edit: PRECISELY what I was looking for!
Wish I could do more for you than just a single good answer vote...
Thanks a lot for the time and sifting through my ideas! :D